# How to copy log of backup activity?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, logs

I'm very new to shell scripting and to Linux, and I need help with an assignment.
The task is to write a shell script to help user backup their folder/files. But this task also needs us to show what happens during the backup process in the log. 
How do I find and copy the log to a txt file base on the date and time the user decides to back up their file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect the output to a file and `$(date ...)` as part of the filename.

e.g.:

```
/path/to/backup_script.sh > /path/to/log/backup_$(date +%F).log
```

or the same within the script:

```
rsync -av ... > /path/to/log/backup_$(date +%F).log
```